# How do i let the user enter an array less than 10 elements C++

Tags: c++, arrays, element

I'm trying to get the smallest number in an array. The user has to enter the number of elements. The highest number of elements that I want is 10.

I tried writing an `if` condition, but I don't think I'm doing it right.

```cpp
int main(){
    int x, e;
    int arr[10];        

    cout << "Enter number of elements(1 to 10)" << endl;
    cin >> e;

    for(x = 0; x < e; x++){
        cout << "Enter number" << x+1 << " : " << endl;
        cin >> arr[x];

        if (arr[x] > 10){
            cout << "Try entering a number <= 10";
        }
```

I expect if the user enters a number of elements higher than 10 it will print `"Try entering a number"`, but the user is able to enter a higher than 10 elements and then it will only take the first 10 elements.

Comment: You want to check the value of `e` after you read it from the user.

Comment: Please spend more time debugging your code and figure out what's going on and what's not going on.

Comment: Been trying for a good minute man couldn't figure it out.. if you could drop some hints i appreciate it

Comment: @AlexandreVaillancourt I'm new to the programming world.. I promise you i spent sometime trying to debug

Comment: You'll have to spend more time than "a good minute". People are paid to spend _hours_ figuring out issues. The more time you spend debugging those kind of issues yourself, the more likely you'll spot them before even writing them.

Comment: I love it that we have such resources as Stack Overflow. But there's a certain amount of "doing it yourself" that will be invaluable to becoming a better programmer. :) This is one of those cases, in my opinion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are doing wouldn't prevent them from adding a number greater than 10 to the array because you are still adding the number to the array. you want something like

```cpp
int main(){

  int x, e;
  int arr[10];

  cout<< "Enter number of elements(1 to 10)"<<endl;

  cin>>e;
  for(x = 0; x < e; x++){

    cout<<"Enter number"<< x+1<< " : "<<endl;

    cin>>arr[x];

    while(arr[x] > 10){
      cout<<"Try entering a number <= 10\n";
      cin>>arr[x];
    }
  }
}
```

however that will prevent them from adding a number greater than 10 to the array. I believe what you are wanting is to prevent them from making e greater than 10. For that you could do something like this.

```cpp
int main(){

    int x, e;
    int arr[10];

    cout<< "Enter number of elements(1 to 10)"<<endl;

    cin>>e;
    while(e > 10)
    {
        cout<< "Enter number of elements(1 to 10)"<<endl;
        cin>>e;
    }
    for(x = 0; x < e; x++){
        cout<<"Enter number"<< x+1<< " : "<<endl;
        cin>>arr[x];
    }
}
```